# Data folders after upgrading to Cassandra 2.1

Tags: cassandra

The name of the data folders has changed with Cassandra version 2.1:

- {data_folder}/{keyspace_name}/{table_name} (prior 2.1)
- {data_folder}/{keyspace_name}/{table_name}-{table_UUID} (after 2.1)

I have a Cassandra cluster that was upgraded from 2.0.6 to 2.1.2, and after upgrade I ended up with mixed folder namings:

- The data folders for some tables remained {table_name} (old style)
- The folders for newly created tables are {table_name}-{table_UUID} (new style)
- I have tables where the sstables are in {table_name} folder and the index files for that table are in a {table_name}-{table_UUID} folder.

I have two related questions:

1. Is there a way to retrieve the name of the data folders for each table/column family?
2. Can I make my Cassandra node to use the actual naming conventions (e.g. all tables in {table_name}-{table_UUID} folders?

Comment: nodetool upgradesstables did not help